# DNS failure when creating and app

Tags: dns, openshift-origin

I'm following this tutorial http://openshift.github.io/documentation/oo_deployment_guide_vm.html to deploy Openshift origin using VirtualBox in a MacBook air OS X 10.10 (Yosemite).

Once the VM is running, I can execute from the host terminal the following command successfully: `rhc setup --server broker-66587a.openshift.local -l demo`

However, when I try to create an app I get the following error:

```
rhc create-app prueba php-5.5
Application Options
-------------------
Domain:     santiago
Cartridges: php-5.5
Gear Size:  default
Scaling:    no

Creating application 'prueba' ... done


Waiting for your DNS name to be available ...     retry # 1 - Waiting for DNS: prueba-santiago.openshift.local
    retry # 2 - Waiting for DNS: prueba-santiago.openshift.local
    retry # 3 - Waiting for DNS: prueba-santiago.openshift.local
    retry # 4 - Waiting for DNS: prueba-santiago.openshift.local
    retry # 5 - Waiting for DNS: prueba-santiago.openshift.local
    retry # 6 - Waiting for DNS: prueba-santiago.openshift.local
    retry # 7 - Waiting for DNS: prueba-santiago.openshift.local
failure
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
WARNING:  Your application was created successfully but had problems during
          configuration. Below is a list of the issues and steps you can
          take to complete the configuration of your application.

  Application URL: http://prueba-santiago.openshift.local/

  Issues:
    1. We were unable to lookup your hostname (prueba-santiago.openshift.local)
in a reasonable amount of time and can not clone your application.

  Steps to complete your configuration:
    1. Clone your git repo
      $ rhc git-clone prueba

  If you continue to experience problems after completing these steps,
  you can try destroying and recreating the application:

    $ rhc app delete prueba --confirm

  Please contact us if you are unable to successfully create your
  application:

    Support - https://www.openshift.com/support

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```

Any idea why this behavior? Thanks